# Not able to display data according to id in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a list of clients and on click of each client i wish to display details of that particular client only, for this i used the following code.

The view of client list is something like this

```
id  fullname
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

> When i click on A i get redirected to other page whose url is http://localhost/projname/admin/client/1
>
> When i click on B i get redirected to other page whose url is
>   http://localhost/projname/admin/client/2
>
> And so on.... the id keeps on changing depending on the click

But the issue is that when i try to display the data in client_detail_view.php page i get the data of first id only i.e id=1

Structure of codeigniter is

```
controllers
    -admin.php
model
    -admin_model.php
views
    -admin  
        -client_view.php
        -client_detail_view.php
```

Code for admin.php

```
public function client($clientid)
        {
            $data['client_data'] = $this->admin_model->get_client($clientid);
            $this->load->view('admin/client_detail_view',$data);
        }
```

Code for admin_model.php

```
public function get_client($id)
            {
                $query = $this->db->get('users');
                $this->db->where('id', $id);
                return $query->row();
            }
```

Code for client_view.php

```
<?php foreach($client as $perclient): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php echo "<td><a href='". base_url() ."admin/client/".$perclient->id."'>" . $perclient->fullname . "</a></td>"; ?>
        <td><?php echo $perclient->email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $perclient->contactno; ?></td>
    </tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Code for client_detail_view.php

```
<?php echo $client_data->fullname; ?>
```

Comment: At least, swap 2 lines: `$this->db->where('id', $id); $query = $this->db->get('users');'
                `

Comment: `model` folder name must be `models`

Comment: @splash58 thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change in model function :

**admin_model.php**

```
public function get_client($id)
{
     $this->db->where('id' => $id);
     $query = $this->db->get('users');
     return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like query is run beofre setting where so it is rightly returning the first record only.
Set where condition beofre query